# Grub 2 does not access /dev/mmcblk0p1, the SD Card

Tags: grub2, sd-card

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit Desktop) and would like to have one of the boot partitions to be on the SD Card, which is formatted as ext4, and is /dev/mmcblk0p1. Grub boots from the hard drive and I want it to stay that way.

When I interrupt the boot process and use the Grub command line, the **ls** command only lists the hard drive. It does not list the SD Card.

Further information: I had manually added /boot/grub/device.map containing (hd1) /dev/mmcblk0 but (hd1) did not show up with grub command line **ls**.

Next, I deleted my manually produced /boot/grub/device.map file and created one using: sudo grub-mkdevicemap -n /dev/mmcblk0p1 which resulted in:
(hd0) /dev/disk/by-id/mmc-SP256_0xc0137d70 (hd1)
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-AXNS381E-256GM-B_2F4120019993

Then, sudo update-grub.
But that did not work either. The Grub command line still listed only hd0, the hard drive. I have done hours of research and trials without any success.

How can I access mmcblk0p1 from Grub 2, in order to use it as one of the boot partitions?

Comment: Can grub even see the SD card reader on boot? Those rarely get initialized without extra modules or BIOS tinkering.

Comment: My research found suggestions on various forums to add the following modules, As root:
echo "mmc_core" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo "mmc_block" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo "sdhci" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo "sdhci-pci" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
update-initramfs -vu -k all
update-grub
I did this, but grub still does not "see" the SD Card.

Comment: grub is started before initramfs. grub loads initramfs for the system you choose to boot.

Comment: @Moiriin Are you saying that it is not possible for grub to have access to the the SD Card reader that is built into the computer?